# TextField different margins compared using TextFieldStyle

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

When I try to use `TextFieldSyle`, I get different internal margins, although I simply set `border.color: "gray"` and `color: "lightgray"`.

Why with the `TextFieldSyle`:

1. text is higher. Seems OK, when placeholder text.
2. bigger left margin
3. What is the dotted bounding boxes around the `TextField`s?

**with text**

[image]

**with placeholder text**

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

Item {

    TextField {
        id: noStyle
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 100
        height: 24
        text: ""

        font.pixelSize: 20
        placeholderText: "0.0"
    }


    TextField {
        transformOrigin: Item.BottomLeft
        id: withStyle
        x: 0
        y: -46
        width: 100
        height: 24
        text: ""
        smooth: true
        enabled: true

        font.pixelSize: 20
        placeholderText: "0.0"

        style: TextFieldStyle {

            background: Rectangle {
                border.color: "gray"
                color: "lightgray"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these screenshots from QML designer? If so, you must look at what the application is really doing.

Comment: Yes, but the same thing is in the application

Comment: It looks like a bug. You might wish to inspect the `TextField` sources to see where it might be messing up. It should be a small patch to fix that.